How do I implement the new VectorSymbol and MatrixSymbol with numeric data?
This post by @xzczd sent me down the rabbit hole trying to use numeric data with the portfolio optimization example in the Documentation for VectorSymbol
Here is the code in the documentation
x = VectorSymbol["x", n]

\[Mu] = VectorSymbol["\[Mu]", n]
\[CapitalSigma] = MatrixSymbol["\[CapitalSigma]", {n, n}]
Subscript[\[Mu], p] = \[Mu] . x
Subscript[\[Sigma], p] = Sqrt[x . \[CapitalSigma] . x]

A = MatrixSymbol["A", {n, n - 1}]
y = VectorSymbol["y", n - 1]
b = UnitVector[n, n]

cond = D[Subscript[\[Mu], p]/Subscript[\[Sigma], p] /. x -> A . y + b,
    y] == 0

Here is simple three asset data for the no short sale version of Markowitz where A is the covariance matrix and y is the vector of returns
A = {{.0146, .0187, .0145}, {.0187, .0854, .0104}, {.0145, .0104, \
.0289}}
y = {{.062}, {.146}, {.128}}

Then this code
cond /. A . y + b -> x

produces a symbolic answer when the "old" method (pre VectorSymbol and MatrixSymbol) produces these weights
Stock 1: 50.12%
Stock 2: 28.21%
Stock 3: 21.68%

(1) What is $\Sigma$? You didn't specify it's numeric values. (2) You shouldn't redefine your symbols with data. Instead, do cond /. A . y + b -> x /. {A -> {{...}}, y -> {{...}}}. (3) Then you use Solve, but you have to specify the dimensions: Block[{n=3}, Solve[..., x]].

I have learned (?) that these new expressions are not intended for numerical work so am asking this question be closed.
